# Java can't find files?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, build

I'm working in Netbeans and I'm trying to build the project. Whenever I build it and try and run the jar file nothing happens. If I run it in netbeans, however, it works. My guess would be that when I compile it it can't find the text files which include information about how big to make the frame so it couldn't load without it. But I don't know why then it would work in netbeans. I have the textfiles on the same level as my src, build, nbproject folders and all that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your application is using a relative pathname. Try to set full pathname to file and test it one more time.